# Compile libxgboost.so fail when install xgboost under cygwin of win10-64bit

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, fopen, xgboost

I use python under **cygwin** and now I need to install **xgboost**.

When I use xgboost in windows. I first use **mingw** to make **libxgboost.dll** and then use `python setup.py install` to successfully install.

But in cygwin, what I need is **libxgboost.so** . So I follow [steps of xgboost doc](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#build-the-shared-library) step by step.

And when I do make in cygwin, error raises:

```
fopen64 not declared
```

I'm not sure how to avoid this and to enable fopen64...

**And how to build and install xgboost under cygwin environment? NOT build to use under windows!!**

===============================
Followed the comment :
I run to this error when execute
`python setup.py install` in ./python-package

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
  File "xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
    'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
__builtin__.XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
List of candidates:
/home/gaoben/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/libxgboost.so
/home/gaoben/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
/home/gaoben/xgboost/python-package/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so
```

**btw..**
In win, is there any linux-like tools that makes developing easier?
I choose cygwin because it's easy to config developing env...
e.g. with the help of apt-cyg..

Answer (score 0):

fopen64 is defined on 32 bit to allow 64bit operation. However on cygwin 64 bit it should be replaced by fopen.

add some

```
#if defined(__x86_64__)
#define fopen64 fopen
#endif
```

in

```
./dmlc-core/src/io/local_filesys.cc
./dmlc-core/src/io/single_file_split.h
./rabit/include/rabit/internal/utils.h
```

and lib/libxgboost.dll will be built for cygwin.

Comment: Well, I want to use xgboost in python of **cygwin**, not windows. Follow your method, I successfully generated libxgboost.dll, But it requires **libxgboost.so**. Is it possible to make a *.so file under cygwin and to use ?

Comment: shared lib on cygwin/windows are *.dll not *.so. Why do you think you need libxgboost.so ?

Comment: I update the question above. when I run `python setup install`. It says need libxgboost.so

Comment: It seems a bad assumption from the setup. One possible trick is to copy libxgboost.dll as libxgboost.so.